# I have created an ec2 instance and succesfully pointed it to domain but the thing is where should i place cakephp file?

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

So i have /var/www/html folder and I placed all the file in html folder on home page is loading . so should i make domainname.com folder inside var/www/html ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure apache's vhosts correctly.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Alternatively, you may want to look into using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy your application as it takes care of all the configuration for you.